# How to add background color to a single row which contains multicolumns?

Tags: tables, colortbl

I want to add background color in the header part of my table which contains grouped columns:

```
\multicolumn{8}{ p{6.0in} }{ \textbf{ PARTNER } } & \hfill\textbf{ TOTAL PAYABLES }  \\
```

A simple `\rowcolor` does not color the whole row but the ungrouped column only.
How to color the whole row?

Comment: if you have a colortbl dated 2012 it should work

Comment: or if not use \cellcollor{blue}

Answer (score 5):

Using `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|*9{c|}}
    \rowcolor{gray!30}\multicolumn{8}{ |p{4.0in}|}{ \textbf{ PARTNER } } & \textbf{TOTAL PAYABLES}  \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This will also work with `colortbl` (with the latest version as suggested by David)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|*9{c|}}
    \rowcolor{gray!30}\multicolumn{8}{ |p{4.0in}|}{ \textbf{ PARTNER } } & textbf{TOTAL PAYABLES}  \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `[table]{xcolor}` is just telling `xcolor` to load `colortbl` so the two versions are the same really.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: True. It is doing same thing differently ;-) Thanks .